# Вывести из базы данных всех проголосовавших

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Добрый день.

У меня есть две таблицы: dle_vote и dle_vote_result. Они имеют такую структуру
dle_vote_result - id, vote_id (ид вопроса), name (имя проголосовавшего), answer (номер варианта ответа).
dle_vote - id (ид вопроса), title (название опроса), body (содержит, варианты ответа на вопрос).
Мне нужно вывести на сайте, кто и за какой вариант ответа проголосовал, в зависимости от вопроса.
Т.е., например, у меня есть два опроса - Как дела? и Как Погода?
Мне нужно, чтобы на сайте вывело:
Как дела?
lingvo - 1 (можно и вариант ответа) либо нормально
test - 2 либо отлично
и т.д.
Как Погода?
lingvo - 0 (можно и вариант ответа) либо плохо
test - 1 либо сойдет
и т.д.

Пока пришел к такому виду, он выводит всех пользователей по всем опросам (исключая гостей). 
На данный момент имеет вот такой вид:
2 (id вопроса) lingvo (ник пользователя) - 0 (выбранный вариант ответа), 2test - 1, 1lingvo - 1, 1test - 2,

```
<?PHP
$result = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT `vote_id`, `answer` , `name`  FROM `". PREFIX ."_vote_result` ORDER BY `vote_id` DESC");
$row = @mysql_fetch_array($result);

while ($row = $db->get_row()) {
if ($row['name'] != 'guest'){
  echo "".$row['vote_id'] ;
  echo "<a href='/user/".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</a>".$row['title']." - ".$row['answer'].", ";}
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38208/3/0

```
select title, name, answer from dle_vote_result as vr inner join dle_vote as v on vr.vote_id = v.id
```

Comment: Да все верно, большое спасибо! Немного php запрос под себя переделаю, и вообще идеально будет. Еще раз благодарю!